# Is there a way to get queries that I look up and run?

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to catch the query statements (SELECT) used when requesting database information on the web in a separate environment between the web and the database server in real time.

The server environment is sql-server 2017 and I would like to extract the specific conditional statements of the query statement that I request, for example, by inserting a conditional statement (WHERE).

I've used the above query statements, but I don't think I can find them well.

```
SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%WHERE ID="root"%';
```

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to run a Profiler Trace, but if you want, you can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 500  qs.creation_time, qs.execution_count, qs.total_worker_time as total_cpu_time
        , qs.max_worker_time as max_cpu_time, qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.max_elapsed_time, qs.total_logical_reads
        , qs.max_logical_reads, qs.total_physical_reads, qs.max_physical_reads
        ,qs.total_logical_writes, qs.max_logical_writes
        ,t.[text], qp.query_plan, t.dbid
        , t.objectid, t.encrypted, qs.plan_handle, qs.plan_generation_num 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS t 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp 
WHERE qs.creation_time BETWEEN DateAdd(minute , -30, GetDate()) AND GetDate()
ORDER BY total_cpu_time DESC;
```

Comment: @m aestro - did that work? how did you go?

Comment: To be exact, I would like to check the queries currently running in real time to see if a specific query is running.

assuming that someone searches for a user named "USER", is there a way to check the query in real time?

Comment: thank you ellis. I updated the text. can you look at it again?